# PHP-FPM error: Primary Script unkown

Tags: linux, php, nginx

I have a strange bug in my nginx / php-fpm code, I'm trying to set up my development machine to use nginx instead of php's built-in server, but it's not working to good so far:

```
FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: local.dev, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock:", host: "local.dev"
```

and my `local.conf` file for nginx:

```
server {
  server_name local.dev www.local.dev;
  root /home/richard/Projects/local/web;
  index app_dev.php;

  location / {
      try_files $uri /app_dev.php$is_args$args;
  }

  location ~ \.php {
      fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
  }

  error_log /var/log/nginx/local_error.log;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/local_access.log;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/local_scripts.log scripts;
```

}

`local_scripts.log` seems correct:

```
/home/richard/Projects/local/web/app_dev.php > GET / HTTP/1.1
```

And i have `chmod +x` all the folders from /home to /web...

Please advice, I think I have looked at all php-fpm / nginx questions here (and there are sooo many)

Also, php-fpm runs as root, the unix socket files is created for user  `richard` with the rights `0777`, and the pool is running with my username `richard` and nginx is running with user `richard`